# PHP handle requests on path level in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I wonder if it is possible to have PHP to handle URL requests on a path style base ?

E.g.  http://my.server.com/basepath/ would be the "base path" of the handler

If a URL like http://my.server.com/basepath/file.ext?parm1=test&parm2=exit

then the "base" PHP script would be called, and recognize, that a parameter was specified as file.ext - and GET parameters parm1 and parm2 could be obtained the usual way.

Is it possible? Any reference to any examples ?

I suspect it can be achieved using mod_rewrite - but I am not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and redirect every request to one PHP script, do the deciding logic there and then `include` or `readfile` the requested data.